# .net winform Grid Alternatives?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, xtragrid

I am using vb.net / Winform 2010.
I am looking for a free (or very cheap) alternative to the DataGridView, one that looks more like what I see on ads for XTraGrid. Something that will multiple lines per records, and for lines to be rolled up, and expanded by clicking, etc.

Comment: Decent grid controls cost money.  Shopping advice is off topic at SO.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this open source grid control.  http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/csharpgridcontrol.aspx